# Error when connecting image View to cell declaration

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am getting a story board error that is connection imageInCell cannot have a prototype object as its destination.  I am trying to connect an image view to a cell class and I am getting this message.  I am trying to use the UICollection View. I have added this code and is getting the error

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageInCell;
```

For some reason even I delete the code I still have the error remaining.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're attempting to create this property somewhere other than in a subclass of UICollectionViewCell, it makes sense that this would generate an error. At run time, you would have one reference to multiple image views and wouldn't be able to properly configure them.

Instead, create a subclass of UICollectionViewCell and add that property there. Then you can go to interface builder and modify "Custom class" in the Identity Inspector the your new subclass and link the image view in the prototype to your property.

Now, after importing the new cells class replacing the UICollectionViewCell in cellForRowAtIndex, etc.. with your new one, you'll be able to do things like `[myCell.imageInCell setImage:someImage];`

Comment: I have already  made a class for both cell and Collection View

Comment: @apple1384792 My main point was are you linking the image view in Interface Builder to an IBOulet created outside of the cell subclass?